# Mocking a method which is in the same class in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

my code goes like this I am trying to mock the htttputility urlencode method which I am using in GetUrlToSurveyMonkeyAuthentication method.

```
    //this is the method which uses urlencode method which is in the same class
    public string GetUrlToSurveyMonkeyAuthentication(string redirectUri, string clientId, string apiKey)
    {
        string urlToOauthSurveyMonkeyAuthentication = SurveyMonkeyBaseUrl + AuthCodeEndUrl + ParameterSeparator + ParameterRedirectUriName + UrlEncodes(redirectUri) + ParameterAdditioner + ParameterClientIdName + UrlEncodes(clientId) + ParameterAdditioner + ParameterResponseTypeName + UrlEncodes(ResponseType) + ParameterAdditioner + ParameterAPIKeyname + UrlEncodes(apiKey);
        return urlToOauthSurveyMonkeyAuthentication;
    }
    // my urlencode method which needs to be mocked it is in the same class SurveyMonkeyAPIService
    public virtual string UrlEncodes(string value)
    {
        return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value);
    }
```

my test method goes like this

```
     [Test]
    public void GetUrlToSurveyMonkeyAuthenticationTest()
    {
        var mockUrlEncodeMethod = new Moq.Mock<ISurveyMonkeyAPIService>();
        mockUrlEncodeMethod.CallBase = true;
        mockUrlEncodeMethod.Setup(x => x.UrlEncode(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(TestData.TestData.SamplehttpUtilityURLEncodeMockString);
        string tempURL = mockUrlEncodeMethod.Object.GetUrlToSurveyMonkeyAuthentication(TestData.TestData.SampleRedirectUri, TestData.TestData.SampleClientId, TestData.TestData.SampleApiKey);
        Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(tempURL);
    }
```

my test fails it always returnsnull value , I have tried removing the virtual keyword , I have an interface which has these two method definitions, I have no parameter constructor.I am using Nunit to test these methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mocking an **interface**:

```
var mockUrlEncodeMethod = new Moq.Mock<ISurveyMonkeyAPIService>();
```

You want to mock a **class**, so that *some* implementation is available:

```
var mockUrlEncodeMethod = new Moq.Mock<SurveyMonkeyAPIService>();
```

Moq will be able to mock virtual methods of said class and call actual implemenation of non-virtual ones.

Comment: If I try to do that I am getting this exception
Moq.MockVerificationException:The following setups were not matched:SurveyMonkeyAPIService x => x.UrlEncode(It.IsAny<String>())